# Alfresco search does not work on the files that is uploaded by Rest Api but it works on files uploaded by Share

Tags: alfresco

when I upload files in the Alfresco UI (Share) the search works fine and I can do a full text search and it shows these files as result. but the search does not work on files that was uploaded by the Alfresco Rest Api!

what is the problem?

I am using Alfresco community last edition and its docker deployment.

update: 
solr logs:

```
solr6_1                  | 2020-05-04 05:50:41.010 ERROR (qtp915349526-13) [   x:alfresco] o.a.s.s.HttpSolrCall null:java.lang.NullPointerException
solr6_1                  |  at org.alfresco.solr.query.Solr4QueryParser.getContentStore(Solr4QueryParser.java:195)
solr6_1                  |  at org.alfresco.solr.query.Solr4QueryParser.<init>(Solr4QueryParser.java:168)
solr6_1                  |  at org.alfresco.solr.query.Lucene4QueryBuilderContextSolrImpl.<init>(Lucene4QueryBuilderContextSolrImpl.java:64)
solr6_1                  |  at org.alfresco.solr.AlfrescoSolrDataModel.getLuceneQueryBuilderContext(AlfrescoSolrDataModel.java:1401)
solr6_1                  |  at org.alfresco.solr.AlfrescoSolrDataModel.getFTSQuery(AlfrescoSolrDataModel.java:1456)
solr6_1                  |  at org.alfresco.solr.query.AlfrescoFTSQParserPlugin$AlfrescoFTSQParser.parse(AlfrescoFTSQParserPlugin.java:105)
solr6_1                  |  at org.apache.solr.search.QParser.getQuery(QParser.java:168)
solr6_1                  |  at org.apache.solr.handler.component.QueryComponent.prepare(QueryComponent.java:161)
solr6_1                  |  at org.apache.solr.handler.component.AlfrescoSearchHandler.handleRequestBody(AlfrescoSearchHandler.java:323)
solr6_1                  |  at org.apache.solr.handler.RequestHandlerBase.handleRequest(RequestHandlerBase.java:173)
solr6_1                  |  at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.execute(SolrCore.java:2477)
solr6_1                  |  at org.apache.solr.servlet.HttpSolrCall.execute(HttpSolrCall.java:723)
solr6_1                  |  at org.apache.solr.servlet.HttpSolrCall.call(HttpSolrCall.java:529)
solr6_1                  |  at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:361)
solr6_1                  |  at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:305)
solr6_1                  |  at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1691)
solr6_1                  |  at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:582)
solr6_1                  |  at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:143)
solr6_1                  |  at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:548)
solr6_1                  |  at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:226)
solr6_1                  |  at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1180)
solr6_1                  |  at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:512)
solr6_1                  |  at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:185)
solr6_1                  |  at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1112)
solr6_1                  |  at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
solr6_1                  |  at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:213)
solr6_1                  |  at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:119)
solr6_1                  |  at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:134)
solr6_1                  |  at org.eclipse.jetty.rewrite.handler.RewriteHandler.handle(RewriteHandler.java:335)
solr6_1                  |  at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:134)
solr6_1                  |  at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:534)
solr6_1                  |  at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:320)
solr6_1                  |  at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:251)
solr6_1                  |  at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:273)
solr6_1                  |  at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:95)
solr6_1                  |  at org.eclipse.jetty.io.SelectChannelEndPoint$2.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:93)
solr6_1                  |  at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.ExecuteProduceConsume.executeProduceConsume(ExecuteProduceConsume.java:303)
solr6_1                  |  at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.ExecuteProduceConsume.produceConsume(ExecuteProduceConsume.java:148)
solr6_1                  |  at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.ExecuteProduceConsume.run(ExecuteProduceConsume.java:136)
solr6_1                  |  at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:671)
solr6_1                  |  at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$2.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:589)
solr6_1                  |  at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
```

Comment: There is normally a short lag between when a document is uploaded and when it is searchable, as the indexing happens in batches in another process. Are you trying to search immediately, or some minutes later? Are you seeing any errors around index tracking?

Comment: no, I waited for 15 minutes. I clearly do see different behavior in search for files uploaded by share and rest api.

Comment: I wish I had chosen Nuxeo in the first place.

Comment: 30 seconds is possible, 15 minutes shouldn't happen! What do your logs say?

Comment: I do not see anything in solr log

Comment: What is your exact Alfresco version

Comment: Alfresco community 6.2 ga (solr 1.4.0)

Comment: I am frustrated, I have no idea what to do. when I upload new files using rest API, I can see from solr web UI that indexed files numbers increases, but search does not work!

Comment: additional info: I apply a custom aspect for files uploaded by rest API. this aspect has no behavior, it only have a single text properties, nothing more.